# jquery animating different img widths

Tags: jquery, image, width, jquery-animate

I've been searching for an answer for a long time with no avail, so it's time to ask.
I'm trying to use `.animate()` to change the size of an image once clicked. The first state of the image would be a thumbnail size, which would animate to the image's original size, then to a thumbnail again.

edit: images load with 150px width by default.

The problem is, not all the images have the same "original" size so I need a way to tell one generic function to switch to the current image's original size.

This is my current code which loads on $(window).load:

```
$('img[class=resize]').click(function (){
        if ($(this).width() != 150)
        {
            $(this).animate({width: '150px'}, 400);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).animate({width: ''}, 400);
        }
    });
```

Now this obviously doesn't work the way I want it, because `.animate()` thinks when I say `width: ''` I want to make the width = 0. Any suggestions how I should go about this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit and read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Do the `<img>` tags have height/width set on them in the page when it loads, either directly as attributes or via CSS?

Comment: Yes, the images load with a width of 150px.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:  When you write an image to the page, add a class or some other attribute that is the image's original width, then when you animate it back to its original size, try `$(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('original_size_attribute_of_your_choosing')}, 400);`

tl,dr: save the original size in an attribute of each image.